# can't pickle _thread._local objects error

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I tried to implement Vizwiz-vqa with PyTorch from [DenisDsh
link](https://github.com/DenisDsh/VizWiz-VQA-PyTorch)

I have an error while running `train.py`. This is Vizwiz vqa source code from 2018, Grand Vizwiz vqa challenge. I want to implement this source code but I can't proceed with this type of error.

It seems like there is a pickler error while using `for item in tq` line.  However, I don't know what to change in `for item in tq` line. I don't have any idea about pickle thread error in `reduction.py` module

[image]